# Ionic 3.9.2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT and unable to ping dev server from within network

Tags: windows, networking, ionic-framework, timeout, ping

I'm having difficulties getting ionic --livereload to work.  When I deploy the app to the device with the -l flag, I get a the following error:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I thought it might be a firewall issue so I tried the following,  none of which worked:

OS: Windows 10. Firewall and anti-virus: standard windows defender bundled with the OS.

1. I added a rule to open ports 8100, 35729, 53703 (inbound and outbound, to be sure).
2. Disabled the firewall on all network types.
3. Also disabled the antivirus.
4. Changed USB ports I was using to deploy the app to device!

So far I've found:

I cant access the dev server i.e. staticIP:8100 from Chrome on my device. 
I also tried pinging and tracerting my PC from other computers within the network and both timed out.

However, I am able to ping my mobile device and other network computers from my PC. It's inbound pings that timeout.

I fiddled with network settings to ensure PC discovery was on and filesharing was enabled. I also enabled file and printer sharing rules (to domain level).

I think the problem accessing staticIP:8100 from elsewhere in my network (including the mobile device itself) is the cause of the time out error - is there some obscure network setting I might have missed that could be blocking access to the host PC from within the network?

I am able to access shared folders on my PC from another networked PC and my PC is showing as present in the network on other network computers.

(Other things I've tried: 
I also played around with the changes to config.xml suggested elsewhere on Stackoverflow and further afield, these made no difference and I suspect the real problem is a network setting somewhere. I've also updated Node, Cordova and Ionic).

Ionic info:

```
cli packages:

  @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
  ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

  cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
   Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

   Node : v8.9.0
   npm  : 5.8.0
   OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

   ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

   backend : pro
```

Any suggestions very welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - IP settings were incorrect, in particular the subnet mask was wrong.

**Longer answer**
I'd set up the IP settings using the new windows 10 WiFi settings menu (not the usual network centre -> wifi properties -> Internet Protocol version 4 ..).

In here, I'd incorrectly entered the subnet prefix length, it's 255.255.255.0, so should be 24.